# iOS swift append 2 multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to append 2 arrays and I get the following error message.

> Cannot convert value of type '[[String.SubSequence]]' (aka 'Array>') to expected argument type '[String]'

This is my code.

```
func getFiles() {
    print("Enter getFiles")
    arrayBookName.removeAll()
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "LVAudioBooks", ofType: nil)

    do {
        let items = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path!)

        for item in items {
            var arrayTemp = [item.split(separator: ".")]
            //arrayBookName += [["temp", "help"]]
            arrayBookName.append(arrayTemp) <-- error occurs here**
           //print(arrayBookName, arrayTemp)

        }
    } catch {
        // failed to read directory – bad permissions, perhaps?
    }
    print(arrayBookName.count)
    print(arrayBookName)
    print("Leave getFiles")
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but as **you** created the resource file why don't you use a more reasonable format and why doesn't the file have the proper extension `plist`?

Comment: At this point I am not smart enough to answer your question except I want only m4b and mp3 type files so I will have to figure it out or if you could offer a suggestion

Comment: @user2751396 If my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Answer (score 0):

`String.split(separator:)` returns the type `[Substring]` and not `[String]`.

To convert `[Substring]` to `[String]`, in your case, you can use the following:

`var arrayTemp = [item.split(separator: ".").map({ String($0) })]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```
items.forEach{arrayBookName.append(contentsOf: $0.split(separator: ".").map{String($0)})}
```

instead of :

```
for item in items {
        var arrayTemp = [item.split(separator: ".")]
        //arrayBookName += [["temp", "help"]]
        arrayBookName.append(arrayTemp) <-- error occurs here**
       //print(arrayBookName, arrayTemp)

    }
```